# Use AppleScript to display a system notification with embeded image expanded?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, notifications

The notification system in BigSur is capable of showing a notification with an image which is already expanded, i.e you don't have to click the little down arrow to show the image embedded in the notification. An example can be seen when you receive an Apple message with an image attachment.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect in AppleScript or my other means?